# Disabled checkbox if any is checked

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

I have a problem with my app in Android/[Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

My app has a list with a checkbox created with a resultset from [Firebird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_%28database_server%29).

I need to set enable/false while one checkbox is checked, but I don't have an idea how to make this.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) class instead. This class is used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of radio buttons. Checking one radio button that belongs to a radio group unchecks any previously checked radio button within the same group.

Comment: but, i'm creating the checkboxes programmatically, with resultset of a SELECT in firebird. How i set to only 1 checkbox can checked.

Comment: How many checkboxes do you have? Are they in a `ListView`?

Comment: yes, i don't know the number of checkbox cause is resultset of a select in my database. The checkbox they in a listview

Answer (score 0):

We can disable the check by knowing its property in combination with setEnabled and setChecked methods like below

```
   private CheckBox termsAndConditions;

  termsAndConditions= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


     termsAndConditions.setEnabled(false); // disable checkbox
     termsAndConditions.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: the problem, the checkbox is a resultset, i created without know the number total. My question is when i check one checkboxs, all of others set the enable to false. Only one can check.

Comment: Loop the resultset and set the false for each of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say that you want that on selecting a check box which is outside the list of checkboxes, and all the check boxes inside the list should be disabled? And when the master checkbox is unchecked, all the check boxes are enabled?

To check a checkbox in Android's XML layout file, you can do this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"/>
```

Also, you can take a reference of this check box and do it programmatically like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox);
checkBox.setChecked(true);     //Check the check box
checkBox.setEnabled(false);    //Disable the check box
```

Comment: the problem, the checkbox is a resultset, i created without know the number total. My question is when i check one checkboxs, all of others set the enable to false. Only one can check.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in a list view you can get them:

```
listView.getChildCount()
```

So you can run in a loop and with `listView.getChildAt(wantedChild);`

Antoher way to do so is to save a list of CheckBox objects that you create from the ResultSet and just run on that after that.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You should call `setChoiceMode` method with `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` parameter on your `ListView`. See the example below.

```
public class MyChecklist extends ListActivity {
  private static final String[] items={"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items));
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
  }
}
```

**layout/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
  android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
```